# Filter the data being loaded with MySQL LOAD DATA command

Tags: mysql, filter, load

I am using the following command.

```
LOAD DATA  INFILE 'source.txt'
INTO TABLE tblData
CHARACTER SET utf8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';
```

This works fine, but the source.txt that I get is an 800MB file with only 10% rows that are required by me. I cannot do the filtering on the text file before load. I can filter my results based on the value of one specific column. Is there a way I can specify this condition in my load statement so only the required rows are loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, at least not with `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

You can however create a script that parses your file and only inserts the records that matches your criteria

Answer (score 1):

You can have your script create a temporary file, call LOAD DATA INFILE into the temporary file, and then filter the temporary file into the final destination.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FILE temp LIKE tblData;
LOAD DATA  INFILE 'source.txt'
    INTO TABLE temp
    CHARACTER SET utf8
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';
INSERT INTO tblData (field1, field2)
    (SELECT field1, field2 FROM temp WHERE some condition);
```

If your system is configured to make sure the temporary file stays in memory, you should still get good performance.